# iOS: How to detect which activity type was selected and execute the share screen correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, share

I have this button when touched is suppose to show all the sharing applications that you can share. But, for some reason it shows up blank when I added a function to check for twitter. I have to do two things.One detect if twitter button was touched so that way I can send a short text due to twitter character limit and two show all the sharing features such as facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setCompletionHandler: is called after the sharing is completed, cancelled or fails. You cannot use it to customise what is actually shared.

To be able to customise the sharing you can use [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

A simple example :

Header file :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySharing : NSObject <UIActivityItemSource>

@end
```

Implementation file

```
#import "MySharing.h"
#import <Social/Social.h>

@implementation MySharing


- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
{
    return @"Default text";
}


- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
         itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    NSString *message = nil;
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
        message = @"text for email";
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
        message = @"text for iMessage";
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) {
        message = @"text for facebook";
    } else if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        message = @"text for twitter.";
    } else {
        message = @"a default text";
    }
    return message;
}


- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
              subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
        return @"Object for email sharing";
    }
    return @"";
}
```

If you share an instance of MySharing instead of an NSString what you share will depend on the chosen activity.

Comment: Not exactly how I did it, but it gave me an idea on what to do.